# SyntaxError: invalid syntax в циклe for

Tags: python

Начинаю обучаться питону, решаю задачки. Вот возникла проблема: питон пишет "invalid syntax", ссылаясь на 10 строку (elif i < z:). Не понимаю, в чем проблема.

```
s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s2 = []
len(s) = z
if z == 1:
    print(s[0])
elif z > 1:
    for i in range(0,z):
        if i == 0:
            a2.append(int(s[-1])+int(s[1])
        elif i < z:
            a2.append(int(s[i-1])+int(s[i+1])
        elif i == z:
            a2.append(int(s[-2])+int(s[0])
print(s2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: a2.append(int(s[-1])+int(s[1])`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что должна выполнять эта программа?

Исправил некоторые ошибки:

```
s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s2 = [] #в цикле имя массива было a2, а тут s2[]
z = len(s) #len(s)=z неправильно. Сначала создаем переменную, потом присваиваем значение
if z == 1:
    print(s[0])
elif z > 1:
    for i in range(z): #Если цикл идет от нуля, можно не писать сам 0
        if i == 0:
            s2.append(int(s[-1])+int(s[1])) #не было закрывающей скобочки ')'
        elif i < z:
            s2.append(int(s[i-1])+int(s[i+1])) #не было закрывающей скобочки ')'
        elif i == z:
            s2.append(int(s[-2])+int(s[0])) #не было закрывающей скобочки ')'
print(s2)
```

Comment: Ещё пара замечаний... В условии `elif i < z:` будет вылет за границы списка `s[i+1]` - возможно имелось ввиду `elif i < z - 1:`. Условие `elif i == z:` никогда не выполнится - возможно имелось ввиду `elif i == z - 1:`.